# Firefox 6 :Problem with QueryInterface(nsIDOMWindow::GetIID() in XPCOM component, for browser content window passed from js

Tags: firefox-addon, xpcom, gecko

I am working on adding support for Firefox 6 for my add-on on Mac OS, where the following logic is working in Firefox 4,5 versions but fails in Firefox 6.

XPCOM component has subclass of `IObserverClient` and which adds itself as observer for a custom event.
This custom event is posted from browser overlay.js  passing the selected browser's content window.

```
var observerService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"]
                                .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService);
if (observerService) {
    var data =  gBrowser.selectedBrowser.contentWindow.location.href;

    observerService.notifyObservers(gBrowser.selectedBrowser.contentWindow, JSEventTopic, data);
}
```

In XPCOM components handler, trying to get the `nsIDOMWindow` interface from `nsISupports`

```c
void XXX::Observe(nsISupports *aSubject, const char *aTopic, const PRUnichar *aData)
{
    nsCOMPtr<nsIDOMWindow> pWin;
    aSubject->QueryInterface(nsIDOMWindow::GetIID(), getter_AddRefs(pWin));
}
```

The problem is, with Firefox 6 `pWin` is nil. In Firefox 4 and 5 `pWin` is as expected and not nil.

Comment: This is unlikely to be related to your issue but you should consider using [`do_QueryInterface`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_nsCOMPtr/Reference_Manual#nsCOMPtr.3CT.3E_.3D_do_QueryInterface.28_nsISupports.2A_.29.2CnsCOMPtr.3CT.3E_.3D_do_QueryInterface.28_nsISupports.2A.2C_nsresult.2A_.29): `nsCOMPtr<nsIDOMWindow> pWin(do_QueryInterface(pSubject));`

Comment: I notice that your `Observe` function uses the parameter name `aSubject`, but the code inside the function uses `pSubject` instead. This might just be a copy-paste error, or it might be a serious problem in your actual code.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out , it is a copy-paste error in the post.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem seems to be that whatever object is being delivered as `aSubject` doesn't implement the `nsIDOMWindow` interface, which naturally causes the `QueryInterface` to fail and yield null. You can't QI an object to an interface that it doesn't implement, and you can't QI null to anything.

I don't know off-hand what causred this change, but here are a few things to check that might help you find the real problem:

- Make sure the subject you're receiving isn't null, and that the pointer you're trying to QI is the argument received by the listener method.
- In your JavaScript code, check that the window object you're passing isn't nil, and is actually something that should implement `nsIDOMWindow`.
- Check that `aTopic` contains the value you expect, and not some other event string.

Comment: Looks like there is nothing wrong with code.I can't exactly figure out what has fixed the problem but removing the binarycomponent directive for this dylib  has fixed the problem.
With binarycomponent directive specified in chrome.manifest(binary-component components/XXX5.dylib appversion>=5.0,binary-component components/XXX6.dylib appversion>=6.0 )since both are true for FF6 dylib of ver5 and 6 getting loaded,though the proper dylib's code is getting executed.(deleting FF5dylib from components,it works).The proper version of this dylib is loaded another dylib so entry in chrome not required.

Answer (score 0):

I am not much familiar with add-on development.  But this works for me in my application(C++).

```
nsCOMPtr<nsIDOMWindow> domWindow; 
nsresult rv = mWebBrowser->GetContentDOMWindow(getter_AddRefs(domWindow));

nsCOMPtr<nsIDOMWindowUtils> windowUtils(do_GetInterface(domWindow));
```